# On using CSRF Token in Routing file of custom module throws error?

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules, drupal-8

I used the (_csrf_token: 'TRUE') in the Custom Module of my routing file. So i got error like(**Uncaught PHP Exception Drupal\Component\Serialization\Exception\InvalidDataTypeException: "Unable to parse at line 32 (near "     _csrf_token: 'TRUE'")." at** */home/otc/install/apache2-4/htdocs/test/core/lib/Drupal/Component/Serialization/YamlSymfony.php line 39*
)

When i used in composer manager routing file it works. But on my custom module it throws website encountered in my module path url.

Kindly suggest me how to solve it

Comment: http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/csrf_protection.html

Comment: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal.php/function/Drupal%3A%3AcsrfToken/8.2.x

Comment: Could you suggest me in example. When i put in controller example.php it throws me access denied in authenticated user.